# Board doesn't look the same

Tags: trello-boards

I have 5 boards and all of the sudden one does not look the same as the others, as it always has. It now has a dark blue banner on the left side of the screen that allows you to click on header name for lists and move between them. And the right side no longer has the grey banner that shows members for the board, filter cards, and recent activity on the board.

How do I get it back to the way it was? I need the grey banner back on the right of the screen.

Answer (score 8):

If you click on the left side of the board, you can hide and show the sidebar. The same with the "List Guide", the list of lists on the left side of the board.

Here's an animated image showing how to close the sidebar:

[image: http://blog.trello.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/sidebar-slide.gif]

Comment: Thank you so much! I must have clicked there and not even known it =)  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Helped me too! I hid it by mistake, and watched it vanish! The shaded area that you must click could do with being a bit more visible... unless you hover, nothing indicates that there is hidden functionality, and even when you hover, the shade is very close to the background blue. cheers
Maria

Comment: Sorry about the trouble! I'll try to make it more obvious. A brighter color and tooltip should help.