# I can't see my side bar in Trello

Tags: trello

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Board doesn't look the same](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30718/board-doesnt-look-the-same)

I want to be able to see my 'side bar' menu in Trello (e.g., so I can click on 'see archived items' etc.  My workmates have it, but I don't and I can't seem to find anywhere that will activate this?

Any advice would be great.

Comment: If you hover on the right side, a dark bar will appear.  Clicking it will show the sidebar.

Answer (score 4):

Hover over to the right-hand-side of the screen (just to the left of the grey board border) and your cursor will change to a resize cursor (double-headed arrow) along with a slightly darker vertical blue bar appearing under your cursor and the help text "Collapse or Expand the board sidebar".

Clicking here will expand/collapse the sidebar.

**UPDATE:**

It looks like Trello have (very) recently included a small arrow just to the left of the sidebar to give a visual indication of where to click.
This arrow points right when the sidebar is visible (indicating to collapse it) and points left when it's hidden (indicating where to click to show it).
This is a significant usability improvement, even if you knew where to click.